# What is the most pythonic way to conditionally compute?

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, dynamic-programming

I'm implementing Bayesian Changepoint Detection in Python/NumPy (if you are interested have a look at the [paper](http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/8189/1/PScpt2.pdf)). I need to compute likelihoods for data in ranges `[a, b]`, where `a` and `b` can have all values from `1` to `n`. However I can prune the computation at some points, so that I don't have to compute every likelihood. On the other hand some likelihoods are used more than once, so that I can save time by saving the values in a matrix `P[a, b]`. Right now I check whether the value is already computed, whenever I use it, but I find that a bit of a hassle. It looks like this:

```
# ...
P = np.ones((n, n)) * np.inf  # a likelihood can't get inf, so I use it 
                            # as pseudo value

for a in range(n):
    for b in range(a, n):

        # The following two lines get annoying and error prone if you 
        # use P more than once

        if P[a, b] == np.inf:  
            P[a, b] = likelihood(data, a, b)

        Q[a] += P[a, b] * g[a] * Q[a - 1]  # some computation using P[a, b]
        # ...
```

I wonder, whether there is a more intuitive and pythonic way to achieve this, without having the `if ...` statement before every use of a `P[a, b]`. Something like an automagical function call if some condition is not met. I could of course make the `likelihood` function aware of the fact that it could save values, but then it needs some kind of state (e.g. becomes an object). I want to avoid that.

**The likelihood function**

Since it was asked for in a comment, I add the likelihood function. It actually computes the conjugate prior and then the likelihood. And all in log representation... So it is quite complicated.

```
from scipy.special import gammaln
def gaussian_obs_log_likelihood(data, t, s):
    n = s - t
    mean = data[t:s].sum() / n

    muT = (n * mean) / (1 + n)
    nuT = 1 + n
    alphaT = 1 + n / 2
    betaT = 1 + 0.5 * ((data[t:s] - mean) ** 2).sum() + ((n)/(1 + n)) * (mean**2 / 2)
    scale = (betaT*(nuT + 1))/(alphaT * nuT)

    # splitting the PDF of the student distribution up is /much/ faster. (~ factor 20)
    prob = 1
    for yi in data[t:s]:
        prob += np.log(1 + (yi - muT)**2/(nuT * scale)) 

    lgA = gammaln((nuT + 1) / 2) - np.log(np.sqrt(np.pi * nuT * scale)) - gammaln(nuT/2)

    return n * lgA - (nuT + 1)/2 * prob
```

Although I work with Python 2.7, both answers for 2.7 and 3.x are appreciated.

Comment: can you show us your likelihood function? to make that function work on vectors instead of scalars

Comment: Maybe with the initial value `None`? Then you can use `P[a, b] = likelihood(data, a, b) if not P[a, b]`

Comment: It actually works on Vectors. `a` and `b` are just the ranges of `data` the likelihood is computed on. I'll add it anyway.

Comment: Since the whole array `P` is initialized to be `inf`, shouldn't the condition of the `if` always be true? Or do you change `P` in some other part of your code?

Comment: `P[a, b]` is used several times. So the `if...` statement is used to compute it only once. The first time `P[a, b]` is needed. I actually change it in the `if` statement. The code is somewhat simplified to make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: @user189 since I use a numpy array and not a normal python array I cant put `None` in it, but only numbers. But I need it to be a numpy array for some other computations.

Comment: Do you really need a 2-d Matrix?  Maybe each time  you have to calculate `P[a,b]`,  you can calculate `P[1,a]` and `P[1,b]` separately, store those results and then return the difference.   Later you only do calculations `P[1,x] ` where `x` is previously unseen.

Comment: Why will this give me the right likelihood? I don't see why `P[a, b] == P[1, b] - P[1, a]` should be true. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Ah, you mean in the log representation, right? But note that I compute the posterior based on data[a:b], s.t. P[1, a] and P[1, b] aren't independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a sibling of `defaultdict` for this (you can't use `defaultdict` directly since it won't tell you the key that is missing):

```
class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def get(self, a, b):
        key = (a,b)

        result = self.cache.get(key, None)
        if result is None:
            result = likelihood(data, a, b)
            self.cache[key] = result

        return result
```

Another approach would be using a cache decorator on `likelihood` [as described here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/325205/).

Comment: I like the decorator solution!

Comment: I like the decorator solution as well, but if you need control of the lifetime of the Cache, then the snippet is fine... However, use .get(key) on the dict instead of try:catch, its faster...

Comment: @Retozi: Optimized :-)